# Why is this method showing as undefined on a sub(sub-sub-)-document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

My schema setup includes a series of nested sub-documents, like so (going from most specific to most general):

```js
var damageExpressionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    /*irrelevant properties*/
});

var effectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    damage: [damageExpressionSchema],
    /*irrelevant properties*/
});

var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hit: {
        effect: [effectSchema]
    },
    miss: {
        effect: [effectSchema]
    },
    pass: {
        effect: [effectSchema]
    },
    fail: {
        effect: [effectSchema]
    },
    /*irrelevant properties*/
});

var monsterSchema = new Schema({
  actions: [eventSchema],
  /*irrelevant properties*/
});
```

Each of these schemas includes an `evaluate()` method, which is supposed to iterate through its nested objects and return some value from them. In the samples here, the only thing they're doing is logging that they're firing, then iterating down, though.

```js
damageExpressionSchema.methods.evaluate = function() {
    console.log('damage');
};

effectSchema.methods.evaluate = function() {
    console.log('effect');
    this.damage.forEach(function(damage) {
        damage.evaluate();
    });
};

eventSchema.methods.evaluate = function() {
    console.log('event');
    this.hit.effect.forEach(function(effect) {
        effect.evaluate();
    });
    /*repeat above process for this.miss, this.pass, this.fail*/
};

monsterSchema.methods.evaluate = function () {
    console.log('monster');
    this.actions.forEach(function(action) {
        action.evaluate();
    });
};
```

So, given a `monsterSchema` object like this:

```js
var clawbutt = new monster({
    "actions": [
        {
          "name": "claws",
          "event": "attack",
          "attackType": "melee",
          "attackSubtype": "weapon",
          "reachRange": 5,
          "attackBonus": 4,
          "hit": {
            "effect": [
              {
                "damage": [
                  {
                    "dice": {
                      "dice": 1,
                      "type": 4,
                      "mod": 3
                    },
                    "type": "piercing"
                  },
                  {
                    "dice": {
                      "dice": 2,
                      "type": 6,
                      "mod": 1
                    },
                    "type": "bludgeoning"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "claws",
          "event": "attack",
          "attackType": "melee",
          "attackSubtype": "weapon",
          "reachRange": 5,
          "attackBonus": 4,
          "hit": {
            "effect": [
              {
                "damage": [
                  {
                    "dice": {
                      "dice": 1,
                      "type": 4,
                      "mod": 3
                    },
                    "type": "piercing"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
    ]
});
```

...when I call `clawbutt.evaluate()`, the console should log:

```
monster
action
effect
damage
damage
action
effect
damage
```

And instead, I'm getting an error that `effect.evaluate` is not a function. I know the schema is applied to those effect objects, I know the evaluate() method exists on the schema, but trying to call `evaluate()` on those effect objects errors out. This happens whether it's called in the recursive fashion I describe here or whether I call it directly on the object, like trying `clawbutt.actions[0].hit.effect[0].evaluate()`.

Is this an issue with the way the schema is defined? The schema as it stands is a little bit of a mess because I'm adapting something that was originally using json-schema into Mongoose for the sake of being able to expand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution to this buried in a [comment on a Github](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/249#issuecomment-10052764) issue, so for posterity:

You can't declare a method on a subdocument's schema after embedding the subdocument's schema in another. So putting the declarations in a different order got it working:

```js
var damageExpressionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    /*irrelevant properties*/
});

damageExpressionSchema.methods.evaluate = function() {
    console.log('damage');
};

var effectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    damage: [damageExpressionSchema],
    /*irrelevant properties*/
});

effectSchema.methods.evaluate = function() {
    console.log('effect');
    this.damage.forEach(function(damage) {
        damage.evaluate();
    });
};

var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hit: {
        effect: [effectSchema]
    },
    miss: {
        effect: [effectSchema]
    },
    pass: {
        effect: [effectSchema]
    },
    fail: {
        effect: [effectSchema]
    },
    /*irrelevant properties*/
});

eventSchema.methods.evaluate = function() {
    console.log('event');
    this.hit.effect.forEach(function(effect) {
        console.log('effect', effect);
        effect.evaluate();
    });
    /*repeat above process for this.miss, this.pass, this.fail*/
};

var monsterSchema = new Schema({
  actions: [eventSchema],
  /*irrelevant properties*/
});

monsterSchema.methods.evaluate = function () {
    console.log('monster');
    this.actions.forEach(function(action) {
        action.evaluate();
    });
};
```